# Java and JSTL/EL: How can I compare two integers stored as attributes?

Tags: java, casting, jstl, el

I'm developing a web-app and I have three static variables in my class called AccountManagement that represent the three possible states that can be reached when clicking on a link in an e-mail to activate an account:

```
public final static int ACTIVATION_EXCEPTION_OCCURRED = -1;
public final static int ACTIVATION_CODE_INCORRECT = 0;
public final static int ACTIVATION_SUCCESSFUL = 1;
```

On startup, these are stored in the context as attributes named "activationSuccessful", "activationCodeIncorrect", and "activationExceptionOccurred". When a user clicks on the link in the e-mail in order to activate the account, the request is sent to the AccountManagementServlet, and his/her first name and the result of the activation code check are added as attributes to their session (which is created if they don't have one yet). The attribute names are "firstName" and "activationStatus" (respectively). The servlet then redirects to activation_status.jsp.

The problem i'm having is that, for some reason, the EL equality statements in that JSP don't evaluate, leaving me with a blank page.

I'm thinking it's because I stored them as primitive integers, and they're being retrieved as objects. If so, how can I cast them in to integers for the comparison? And if that isn't the problem, can someone kindly tell me what it may be? If I replace all the servletContext attributes in the code below with their respective integers, EL seems to cast the sessionScope attributes to integers based on the presence of an actual integer and the code works. I don't want to hard-code the numbers in to the jsp, so if someone could help me out here I'd be grateful.  Here is the code for the JSP:

```
<c:choose>
            <c:when test="${sessionScope.activationStatus == servletContext.activationSuccessful}">
                Congratulations ${sessionScope.firstName}, you've activated your account!
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${sessionScope.activationStatus == servletContext.activationCodeIncorrect}">
                Hi ${sessionScope.firstName}, this activation code is incorrect, please try clicking the link in the e-mail (or the copy and paste instructions) again. If you still end up here, <a href ="send_another_activation_code_page.html">you'll need to get another activation code</a>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${sessionScope.activationStatus == setvletContext.activationExceptionOccurred}">
                Hi ${sessionScope.firstName}, an error occurred during activation, please try clicking the link in the e-mail (or the copy and paste instructions) again. If you still end up here, most likely the time period to activate this account has expired. Don't fret, but you can sign up again (with the same e-mail, if you wish) <a href="index.html">here</a>!
            </c:when>

</c:choose>
```

Comment: When you say you're getting a blank page, I'm led to think that there's a JSTL/EL error. Please put your code in a c:catch block and see if there is an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `${servletContext}` (and `${setvletContext}`) is invalid. You need `${applicationScope}` which refers to a mapping of the attribtues of the `ServletContext`. See also the [*Implicit Objects*](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij) chapter in Java EE tutorial for an overview.

---

Regardless, this approach is somewhat whacky. I'd use an enum.

```
public enum ActivationStatus {
    SUCCESSFUL, INCORRECT, EXCEPTION;
}
```

with

```
<c:when test="${activationStatus == 'SUCCESSFUL'}"></c:when>
<c:when test="${activationStatus == 'INCORRECT'}"></c:when>
<c:when test="${activationStatus == 'EXCEPTION'}"></c:when>
```

Comment: Yea, I needed to condense the attributes. I decided to just make them in to a hashmap and store that as an attribute. I would have gone the enum route, but I prefer an actual connection between the context attribute and the statuses (I don't want to rely on the inherent ordering of the enum to dictate what the integer values would be)

Answer (score 0):

You can do `${foo eq bar}`, but I don't think that will solve your problem. I believe `==` should suffice.

I'm fairly certain that you don't need to access request attributes through context, and you can access them directly: `${activationSuccessful}`

One other gotchya I see is that you've misspelled servlet in your third example:

> setvletContext.activationExceptionOccurred

If I were you, I would narrow down the exact error by printing out the values:

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.activationStatus}"/>
<c:out value="${activationSuccessful}"/>
```

etc.

One other option is to handle this server side:

```
String welcomeMessage = // place if stmts, etc.
request.setAttribute("welcomeMessage", welcomeMessage);
```

or you could return booleans:

```
boolean isSuccessful = // if stmt
request.setAttribute("isSuccessful", isSuccessful);
```

then

```
<c:if test="${isSuccessful}">
```

or

```
<c:if test="${isSuccessful eq true}">
```

IMO, having your constants in the jsp is somewhat of a leak.

Comment: "IMO, having your constants in the jsp is somewhat of a leak". I figured someone would say that. The activation status is figured out by the servlet, this is just my way of delegating a single page to redirect to regardless of the outcome, and having the status there dictate what is put there, instead of having three seperate pages. You don't think this is a good idea (I'm asking this sincerely, i'm open to better ideas)?

Comment: After looking at the text again, I think it would be another leak for the message to reside in the servlet since you have markup in the text. I think the path of least resistance is to just return booleans akin to something like `request.setAttribute("isSuccessful", activationStatus == 1);` etc, but that's up to you.